# MS AZURE - AzureWebJobsDashboard - using existing website dashboard string

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service

I was reading through the MS documentation and it says we can attach webjob(s) to an existing website project. So I've created a new Cloud (C#) WebJob under the same solution as my Web app. I have a storage account which I'll be using for the log/diagnostics - its connection string will be assigned to **"AzureWebJobsStorage"**.

Now I am trying to assign the connection string to the existing website dashboard **"AzureWebJobsDashboard"** but when I click on ***View Connection String*** link I get the following popup. I am sure I am doing something funny. Perhaps we cannot use the existing website dashboard and have to create a new storage for that? Help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: trying to understand what you are doing. if you want to link a storage account to your web app, you should use "Mange Link Resources" where you can link other resources e.g SQL Server, Azure Storage Account. "View Connection strings" is empty, i think it is because you didn`t have any connection string setup for your Web App.

Comment: Ahh, well... what I understood was that instead of creating a separate storage account for the "AzureWebJobsDashboard" I could use the existing hosted website dashboard.

Comment: want to confirm my understanding. you have a web app or a webjob, and you have a storage account. you would like to use your storage account within your web app or webjob. Right?  if this is the case you should be use Azure Storage SDK to access your storage account or any storage account as long as you have the access key or SAS key. The view connection string is only showing the data from your appsettings i beleive.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I think I must have misunderstood the help file. I do not think it is possible to use existing Azure website dashboard to display the queue storage as well. The connection string for the storage is composed of the ACCESS KEY while the connection string for the web. is URL based.

Comment: They are separated service. Azure Website dashboard only display website related information. if you want to see Storage Account information, you will have to navigate to Storage Account extension and see from there.

Answer (score 0):

The `AzureWebJobsDashboard` is an App Settings and it will not show up in the Connection strings section

It should just show up in your website's Configure tab in the App Settings and the Web Job will read the value from there.

So all you need to do is to add that AzureWebJobsDashboard to the App Settings of your Web Site and it should work:

[image]